# How to store Novel Editor data in supabase?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks, tailwind-css

In this code i want to store data entered in novel editor in supabase.When i enter title, author, date all the data is successfully stored but the problem in when i enter data in novel editor it doesnt show in data in supabase rather it shows error on this line

```
<Editor value={content} onChange={setContent} />
```

on value the error is

> Type '{ value: MyEditorContent; onChange: Dispatch<SetStateAction>; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { completionApi?: string | undefined; defaultValue?: JSONContent | undefined; extensions?: Extension<any, any>[] | undefined; editorProps?: EditorProps<...> | undefined; onUpdate?: ((content: JSONContent) => void) | undefined; onDebouncedUpdate?: ((content: JSONContent) => void) | undefined; de...'.
> Property 'value' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { completionApi?: string | undefined; defaultValue?: JSONContent | undefined; extensions?: Extension<any, any>[] | undefined; editorProps?: EditorProps<...> | undefined; onUpdate?: ((content: JSONContent) => void) | undefined; onDebouncedUpdate?: ((content: JSONContent) => void) | undefined;

I am unable to find the error.

```
"use client";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { supabase } from "../../../../utils/supabaseClient";
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Navbar from "@/app/shared/Navbar";
import Container from "@/app/layouts/Container";
import "react-quill/dist/quill.snow.css";
import "novel/styles.css";


import { Editor } from "novel";

// Define a custom content type
type MyEditorContent = {
  nodes: Array<{
    type: "paragraph";
    children: Array<{ text: string }>;
  }>;
};

const AdminPage: React.FC = () => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState<string>("");
  const [content, setContent] = useState<MyEditorContent>({
    nodes: [{ type: "paragraph", children: [{ text: "" }] }],
  });
  const [datetime, setDateTime] = useState<string>("");
  const [author, setAuthor] = useState<string>("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e: React.FormEvent) => {
    e.preventDefault();

    // Create a new article object with the form data
    const newArticle = {
      title,
      datetime,
      content,
      author,
    };

    const { data, error } = await supabase
      .from("Articles")
      .upsert([newArticle]);

    if (error) {
      console.error("Error inserting data:", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Data inserted successfully:", data);

      setTitle("");
      setContent({ nodes: [{ type: "paragraph", children: [{ text: "" }] }] });
      setDateTime("");
      setAuthor("");
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Container>
        <h2 className="text-2xl font-semibold mb-4">Create New Article</h2>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="max-w-lg mx-auto">
          <label className="block mb-2">
            Title:
            <input
              className="block w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg px-3 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400"
              type="text"
              value={title}
              onChange={(e) => setTitle(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>

          <label className="block mb-2">
            Date and Time:
            <input
              className="block w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg px-3 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400"
              type="datetime-local"
              value={datetime}
              onChange={(e) => setDateTime(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>

          <label className="block mb-2">
            Author:
            <input
              className="block w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg px-3 py-2 mt-1 focus:outline-none focus:border-blue-400"
              type="text"
              value={author}
              onChange={(e) => setAuthor(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>

          <label className="block mb-4">
            <span className="text-lg font-semibold mb-2">Content:</span>
            <div className="w-full border border-gray-300 rounded-lg shadow-md">
              <Editor value={content} onChange={setContent} />
            </div>
          </label>

          <div className="flex justify-center mt-6 sm:mt-11">
            <button
              type="submit"
              className="text-brown bg-gradient-to-br from-green-400 to-blue-600 hover:bg-gradient-to-bl focus:ring-4 focus:outline-none focus:ring-green-200 dark:focus:ring-green-800 font-medium rounded-lg text-sm px-5 py-2.5 text-center mr-2 mb-2"
            >
              Submit
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </Container>
    </div>
  );
};

export default AdminPage;
```